# Am I misunderstanding how my site is supposed to be deployed?

Tags: deployment, build, sveltekit

My project is to build a completely static site that shows some graphs. The graphs are based on data that is pulled from a third party API. The thing is that I want the graphs to be updated every day. I already built the entire logic that handles the fetching, the compiling the storing of the data in postgresql db and then the querying in order to create summaries of the data that will be used in the graphs. I just don't know how this task is supposed to be triggered when say the site is being deployed via netlify.

It seems that if I run the function that handles this task in svelte.config.js, it will run multiple times during a single deployment, which I didn't expect.

Am I doing this completely wrong or should I just add some check to verify if the daily task was already done?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what my error was, and the solution was to separate this task from Svelktit altogether. I simply put all the code into a plain Node script and hosted the repo on a cheap VPS host, where I could start it via a cron job.

Obviously, the website will be built as a separate project, which can be hosted on some CI/CD service.